# Guess the number within 6 moves

Tags: python, vb.net

I'm building a "guess the number within 6 moves" and I found a python code.
Pyhton code:

```
import math
skippie=raw_input("If you know how to do this, enter skip ")
if skippie=="skip":

found = False
varmin=1
varmax=100
while not found:

    guess = (varmax+varmin)/2
    ans=raw_input("Is your input larger (l), smaller(s), or equal to (e) than " + str(guess) + " ")
    if ans == "L" or ans == "l":
        varmin = guess
    elif ans == "S" or ans == "s":
        varmax = guess
    else:
        print "Yay! I got it!"
        found = True
```

What would be the vb.net version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code could be improved, but I thought it would be more helpful to keep it very close to the original:

```
Console.WriteLine("If you know how to do this, enter skip")
Dim skippie As String = Console.ReadLine()
If skippie = "skip" Then
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    Dim varmin As Integer = 1
    Dim varmax As Integer = 100
    While Not Found
        Dim guess As Integer = (varmax + varmin) / 2
        Console.WriteLine("Is your input larger than (l), smaller than (s), or equal to (e) {0}?", guess.ToString)
        Dim ans As String = Console.ReadLine()
        If ans = "L" Or ans = "l" Then
            varmin = guess
        ElseIf ans = "S" Or ans = "s" Then
            varmax = guess
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Yay! I got it!")
            found = True
        End If
    End While
End If
```

Next time, please *attempt* to translate the code yourself before posting and post your attempt with the result.

**EDIT:** Windows Form Version

```
If InputBox("If you know how to do this, enter skip") = "skip" Then
    Dim varmin As Integer = 1
    Dim varmax As Integer = 100
    Do
        Dim guess As Integer = (varmax + varmin) / 2
        Select Case UCase(InputBox("Is your input larger than (l), smaller than (s), or equal to (e) " & guess.ToString & "?"))
            Case "L"
                varmin = guess
            Case "S"
                varmax = guess
            Case "E"
                MsgBox("Yay! I got it!")
                Exit Do
        End Select
    Loop
End If
```

I made some stylistic changes to this version as well. (Mostly I eliminated unnecessary variables.) The behavior is the same, but in my opinion the second version is more [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) while the first is more [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Comment: thanx Josh..I put this code in  a button, but it doesn't show anything..Improved are allowed.. Sorry i tried to translate, this is my try http://pastebin.com/e5Y48W6V . it s too ugly for posted here :).

Comment: edit1. OK, i'm using a console, but what is the skippie button to click?
i'm thinking it's better use windows form with button and msgbox, without insert letter.

Comment: @MattiaFanti, see edit above. This is still based on the original code, which handles the entire process in one Sub. The code you just shared is a radically different approach (splitting the Sub across multiple button events).